# Permuting values in a pandas dataframe using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, permutation

I am trying to permute the values of a pandas dataframe until a condition is met. My condition is to shuffle values in df.rows[1:6] until the values in the 'sum' row are as close as possible to 100.

I have the following dataframe:

```
       row0        row1        row2     row3        row4        row5    row6
1      6.00    7.333333    8.666667   10.000   11.333333   12.666667   14.00
2      2.00    2.666667    3.333333    4.000    4.666667    5.333333    6.00
3      0.05    0.125000    0.200000    0.275    0.350000    0.425000    0.50
4      0.05    0.125000    0.200000    0.275    0.350000    0.425000    0.50
5      0.10    0.085000    0.070000    0.055    0.040000    0.025000    0.01
6     94.00   92.000000   90.000000   88.000   86.000000   84.000000   82.00
sum  102.20  102.335000  102.470000  102.605  102.740000  102.875000  103.01
```

my loop is as follows:

```
def shuffle():
    df = matrix_gen()
    ind = df.index
    count =0
    while count <100000:
        sampler = np.random.permutation(df.shape[0])
        new_vals = df.take(sampler).values
        df = pd.DataFrame(new_vals, index=ind)
        v = df.loc['sum'].values
        if ((98<v) & (v<100)).any():
            break
        else:
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
    return df

m = shuffle()
print(m)
```

my question is, is there a quicker, more efficient way to arrive at my solution? So far, the condition has not been met.

Comment: quicker? Your program should *never* end. You can never know for sure with this program that there is a better solution. Even generate-and-test would eventually outperform this.

Comment: What function does `count` have? You initialize, increase it but what is it for? When would this `while` loop actually break, looks infinite at first glance?

Comment: This is (presumably) a NP-Hard problem... good luck...

Comment: But it never stops because you have a `while True` and nothing that break that loop.

Comment: Sorry, forgot break!

Comment: It doesn't change, because your break will stop the `for` loop, not the `while` loop

Comment: you should do something like `while count < 6`, something like this (for the most basic fix).

Comment: @Joey: but how do you know that (a) it is optimal at when all the columns are between 98 and 100; and (b) it is possible that all the columns are between 98 and 100 anyway?

Comment: I guess you could do : `v = df.loc['sum'].values; if ((98<v) & (v<100)).any(): break`, if you meant one of them being within the range for breaking out.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : (a) I know that it is optimal because this is my own criteria. (b) I have tested an arrangement that allows the condition to be met. I just want to automate it.

Comment: @Divakar: I need all values in row['sum'] to be >98 <100.

Comment: @Joey Edit the code accordingly, because with the present code, it will only break out of the for loop, not the while loop, as also mentioned in earlier comments.

Comment: @Divakar your code doesn't work for me. ; and : are raising syntax error

Comment: @Joey Those are meant to go into three separate lines. Also, it seems you are simply permuting rows and checking if the last row has ALL values between 98 and 100, which isn't the case with any of the rows. As such, I think you won't have a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161532/discussion-between-joey-and-divakar).

Comment: You seem to shuffle complete rows. The column positions stay the same.

Comment: The 'sum' row must be recalculated too, I guess.

Comment: If your problem is to have all your columns with a sum between 98 and 100, it's not possible as your max value is 94 (in row 6), and it will necessarily be with a 6 in row 1 (as in your example). So you have at least one columns that can't be below 100. If your problem is to have a least one column satisfying this condition, then it's much simpler.